# How to add an element to an array inside an array in JS ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

For example, I know I can use spread operator to add an element to an array in ES6.

```
const arr = ["a","b"]
const newArr = [...arr, "c"]
```

that I get

```
["a","b","c"]
```

But how to implement this in an nested array, like

```
const arr = [["a","b"], ["d"]]
```

I want to get

```
newArr1 = [["a","b","c"], ["d"]]
```

and

```
newArr2 = [["a","b"],["d","c"]]
```

Perhaps we can use

```
[[...arr[0], 'c'], [...arr[1]]]
```

but what if

```
const arr = [["a","b"], ["d"],["e"]]
```

and I still want

```
[["a","b","c"], ["d"],["e"]]
is there a common way?
```

Comment: Maybe mapping the spread operator to each element?

Comment: Is that what you meant? `[[...arr[0], 'c'], [...arr[1]]]`

Comment: yeah Alexandr you're right! But what if the size is not fixed? Like const arr = [["a","b"], ["d"],["e"]]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the array index or use findIndex and find methods, in case you want to remove not based on the index

```js
const arr = [[a,b], [d]]
arr[1].push(c)
//arr = [[a,b], [c,d]]
```

```js
const arr = [['a', 'b'], ['d']]
const array = [...arr]
const arrayIndex = array.findIndex(item => item.find(i => i === 'd'))
if (arrayIndex !== -1) {
  const oldArray = array.find(item => item.find(i => i === 'd'))
  const newArray = [...oldArray, 'c']
  array[arrayIndex] = newArray
}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Yes, but what if I don't want to mutate the original array

Comment: You can create a new variable that recieves your original array value and spread it. I just edit the  post.